# How was Merten's theorem proven on the step comparing the convergence of one sequence and the Cauchy product partial sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-product

I'm trying to understand step 3 of the proof of [Merten's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens'_theorem).

[image]

How is it known that $N*_{sup}|B_i-B|$ term converges slow enough that there is an N where equation 3 is true:
$|a_n|\le\frac{\varepsilon}{3N(\sup_{ i\in\{0,\dots,N-1\} } |B_i-B|+1)}$

Both $a_n$ and $|B_i-B|$ are converging, but the relative rate I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $N$ is defined for in the step before, in view of getting (2). In the third step, $N$ is now a fixed integer: so, defining $\varepsilon'>0$ as
$$
\varepsilon' \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{\varepsilon}{3N(\sum_{i < N}\lvert B_i - B\rvert +1)}
$$
we have that $\varepsilon'$ is "just a number": so since $(a_n)_n$ converges to 0, there exists some $M\geq 0$ such that
$$\lvert a_n \rvert \leq \varepsilon', \qquad \forall n \geq M$$
There is no issue of "relative rate of convergence": $N$ is fixed based on the convergence of $(B_n)_n$, then *once $N$ is fixed* $M$ is defined based on the convergence of $(a_n)_n$.